# triangular Numbers Java

Tags: java, triangular

the problem is there is two types of codes for same result(triangular number)

1.

```
           for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int triangular = 0;

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                triangular = triangular + j;
            }
            System.out.println(i + " = " + triangular);
```

2.

```
int x =1; 
int triangular = 1;

while(x<=10){


System.out.println(x+ "=" +triangular);
 x++;
triangular= triangular+x;

}
```

why for (1) "int triangualr" is 0 and for (2) its 1 ??? idont understand

Comment: Because they aren't identical blocks I assume. Check [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) out.

Comment: Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method 1, int triangular is initialized everytime inside the for loop. Nested for loop is calculating the value for triangular and then you are printing the value

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int triangular = 0;

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                triangular = triangular + j;
            }
            System.out.println(i + " = " + triangular);
       }
```

But in Method 2, Value for x=1 is printed in the first line of the while loop and then the value of x is incremented

```
int x =1; 
int triangular = 1;
while(x<=10){
    System.out.println(x+ "=" +triangular);
    x++;
    triangular= triangular+x;
}
```

*So in first method, value for triangular is calculated starting from 1 and in second method value for triangular is calculated is not calculated for 1st Iteration*

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second code the "triangular" first is printed with value=1 
while in the first code the "triangular" first is increased (goes from 0 to 1) and then is printed with value=1.

So in both cases what you see first is triangular=1.